# Parsing XML with Rails/Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

im new to web development, and im trying to learn how all of this works.  Ive managed to learn alot in 1 day but im stuck now.

Im trying to create an odds site so im using this xml feed to get all the info.  Im able to do a

http://xml.pinnaclesports.com/pinnacleFeed.aspx?sportType=Hockey&contest=no

```
eventdate = doc.css('event_datetimeGMT')[0].text
league = doc.css('league')[0].text
visitingteam = doc.css('participant_name')[0].text
hometeam = doc.css('participant_name')[1].text
```

However Im looking to be more efficient and wondering whats the best way to go to collect all the games, should i run a loop or something? Also Im thinking I should store these in an array instead?  Maybe run a loop to store each event in a separate array.

So lost, thanks in advance!

Comment: [XmlMapping](http://multi-io.github.io/xml-mapping/) may be useful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do a loop, something like this.  Presumably you want these in your database so I'd store them in the database via a match model.

```
doc.xpath('//events/event').each do |event|
  eventdate = event.xpath('event_datetimeGMT').text
end
```